# advanced replace strings in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So, I want to replace the last section of each group with, either a "0", or a space.
input example:

```
16;9116;6
17;10753;6
18;12576;7
19;14597;7
```

output will need to be:

```
16;9116;0
17;10753;0
18;12576;0
19;14597;0
```

is there a wildcard value i can use?

Comment: I found this useful please follow the link. [Advance Notepad Replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/1120379/notepad-advanced-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs simple regular expression.

In the find what box enter `;\d$` and in the replace with box enter `;0`. Ensure that "Regular expressions" and "Wrap around" are ticked. Then click on "Replace all" - or you can click "Replace" multiple times to see more easily that it is working as required.

Explanation of `;\d$`: The `;` matches itself, the `\d` matches one decimal digit, the `$` matches the end of line. If the lines have more digits (e.g. `18;12576;78` should be changed to `18;12576;0`) then change the find string to be `;\d+$`. The `+` signifying one-or-more of the preceding item.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 1):

AdrianHHH's answer is perfect. I just added a screenshot to have little more clarity.

[image]

I would also add, that it is **safer** to use `Replace` to test your find/replace, before applying it to `Replace All`. Some times, if you have a large file, it can have changes, you did not anticipate. My two cents.

Comment: Agree about testing your replace, but remember that menu => Edit => Undo (or control-Z) can be very useful.